# How do I reuse a React Component without having to change its inner props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if that even exists. I am trying to reuse a component, however, the component I am trying to reuse receive props and already handles them inside of the component.

If I reuse this component in another place I am going to have to change all of the props received.

Is that a common thing when developing in React or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: IMO that's a code smell that the reused component needs to be a new component. Other options might be decomposing the parts of the component into a new component so they can be reused if there is an obvious pattern

Comment: Re-Usability is something React is really good at, so I assume your doing something wrong.  Might be best posting some code to explain your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should divide the component with the props to two:

Component A. functionality (and all the props needed)

Component B. a type of container with no props just holding the component A

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes is common and is often resolved with **HoC (High Order Components)**

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Example

```js
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
      console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
    }
    render() {
      // Wraps the input component in a container, without mutating it. Good!
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}

const EnhancedComponent = logProps(WrappedComponent);
```

Comment: Thank for pointing this out! (I'm new to react what do you think of my answer it's just my opinion...)

Comment: In your answer basically are describing an HoC pattern! :)

Comment: Thanks for ensuring that! I was going to add an example but yours is perfect! React is amazing! the logic is logical! ;) thanks for your time!